# What does "I can't stress enough that..." mean?

Tags: meaning

Does it mean "I can't fully express...."?

"**I can't stress enough that** I want to serve as an open door between Silicon Valley and Medicaid," he said.

Source: [Silicon Valley is missing a 'big opportunity' because it doesn't understand poor people - Medicaid chief](http://www.cnbc.com/2017/05/09/medicaid-chief-andrey-ostrovsky-silicon-valley-missing-unicorns.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means

> he can not say **strongly enough** that...

So in a way I can see how you might think

> he can not *(fully)* express himself.

However, but saying this, he actually is expressing himself, that there are no words strong or big or wide enough to fully express how he feels, that he *really* wants to be the door between Silicon Valley and Medicaid.